# cannot create /run/activemq.pid: Permission denied

Tags: activemq-classic, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run ActiveMQ on Ubuntu 16.04. To start ActiveMQ I run this command.

```
/opt/apache-activemq-5.15.10/bin/linux-x86-64$ sudo activemq start
```

It results in this error:

```
INFO: Loading '/usr/share/activemq/activemq-options'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java//bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: changing to user 'activemq' to invoke java
-su: 3: cannot create /run/activemq.pid: Permission denied
INFO: pidfile created : '/run/activemq.pid' (pid '23718')
```

Comment: you should add the code that produce that logs, to let someone to help you

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori i have edited my question with Edited portion in it. Please check and let me know more information if you need.

Comment: The process changed users to activemq, and the likely scenario is that the activemq user doesn't have access to write to `/run`.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the output, the script changes to the `activemq` user:

```
INFO: changing to user 'activemq' to invoke java
```

However, the user `activemq` doesn't have permission to create the file `activemq.pid` in the `/run` directory.

You should either grant the user `activemq` permission to create the file `activemq.pid` in the `/run` directory or use the `ACTIVEMQ_USER` environment variable to specify a user which *does* have permission to create the file `activemq.pid` in the `/run` directory.